# How to get the second solution?

Tags: logarithms

I have this exercise:

Solve for $x$, $(\log x)^{10} = 3$

My development was:

$\log x = \sqrt[10]3$

$10^{\sqrt[10]3} = x$ , this is my solution.

But I still need a solution, according to the symbolab. Which is: $x = \frac{1}{10^{3^{\frac{1}{10}}}}$

But I have not managed to get it on my own, how can I get to this result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In real numbers $\,z^{10}=3\,$ has the roots $\,z = \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt[10]{3}\,$.

Comment: How you know that?

Comment: $z^{10} = (-z)^{10}\,$, so if $\,z\,$ is a root then $\,-z\,$ is also a root. As for why it does not have *more* than two real roots, think at the convexity of $\,z^{10}\,$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this with a much simpler problem: suppose you want to find $y$ such that
$y^{10} = 1.$

Obviously $y = \sqrt[10]1 = 1$ is a solution.

Is there any other solution? Why or why not?

Your solution method has much in common with the method for finding that $y = 1$
in the example above: you have something to the $10$th power, so you assume all you have to do is take the $10$th root.
But this does not give complete solutions, just as taking the square root does not completely solve equations like $x^2 = 1.$

Comment: True, so how i can get all solutions in this type of exercise?

Comment: One way is to remember that raising any number to an even power will give it a positive sign, even if the original number was negative. So working backward, when you take the $n$th root, you have to consider both possibilities, that you had something positive or something negative before taking the $n$th power.